# Accessing an object based on foreign key link in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I currently have some models linked using foreign keys

(reduced) models.py:

```py
class Saga(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    startChapter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    endChapter = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Arc(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    saga = models.ForeignKey(Saga,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default=Saga.get_default_pk)
    startChapter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    endChapter = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Clip(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    arc = models.ForeignKey(Arc,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,default=Arc.get_default_pk)
    chapter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ClipViewer')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, related_name='author_of')
```

Basically all Sagas have a set of associated arcs and every arc has a list of associated clips.

What I want to do is get my Sagas, Arcs and Clips through my API calls and then loop through each saga, getting the associated arcs for that saga and then loop through the arcs, getting the associated clips for that arcs, eg:

```
Saga 1 has arcs 1,2,3
   Arc 1 has clips 1 & 2
   Arc 2 has clip 3
   Arc 3 has clips 4 & 5
Saga 2 has arc 4,5....
```

But templates seem too limited to do this kind of querying, I can't do anything like get the list of associated arcs for a given saga or anything like that and being told:

> Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

doesn't help my problem seeing as I need to perform the data access within a for loop that happens within the template itself.

Any way to perform this kind of data access within the django template or somehow pass the relevant data through the view.

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible to do this in Django templates, say you pass a given `saga_list` queryset to the template - you can access the reverse many-to-one relationship using the `_set` attribute. Django creates this automatically if you do not set a `reverse_name` on your ForeignKey field:

```html
{% for saga in saga_list %} 
{{ saga }}
    {% for arc in saga.arc_set.all %}
        {{ arc }} # access arc properties normally
        {% for clip in arc.clip_set.all %}
            {{ clip }} # access clip properties too
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is true that the logic capabilities of templates is limited, you can't use filters, etc. directly in the template, but then again you wouldn't want to. Use your views/models/managers to do that for you and pass the variables in through context.

Comment: This would work but the problem is I'm getting the Saga object through an API call so it's not a django queryset I can loop through, it's just JSON data

Comment: Then build your JSON in the view first using _set

Comment: Are you suggesting I encode all arc information within each saga using a relational field as such?:

https://pastebin.com/PGPBRMiD